# Xcode does not show @IBAction for UIButton

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton

When i ctrl-drag from a UIButton in storyboard to the viewcontroller class , Xcode is not showing the option to create an IBAction.

[image]

I think this something to do with the project setting because i try to open it to another pc it had the same problem.

**SOLUTION**

Apparently i created an extension of UIButton that causes this problem.

Comment: Please do not add your solution as part of the question. Give it as an answer, and accept your own answer to complete the QA cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Try another way (*my usual way*), **from code** create your @IBAction :

```
@IBAction func myAction(){
  //here your code
}
```

Then **CTRL - drag** to this `@IBAction myAction`